# Obtener numero de la linea y su contenido de un Archivo de texto al encontrar una palabra

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de obtener el numero de la linea y su contenido en donde se encuentre una palabra en especifico.

Ejemplo de salida:

`Palabra: TRACKING ID`
`Numero de Linea: 13`
`Contenido: Tracking ID: 123ABCDEF`

Este es el codigo que tengo hasta el momento que solo me da el contenido, pero me gustaria tambien poder obtener el numero de la linea en donde se encuentra.

Codigo C#

```
var filepath = @"C:/MyText.txt";

string palabra = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).Where(x =>x.Contains("TRACKING")).First();
Console.WriteLine(palabra);
```

Comment: no hagas ReadAllLines, hace un for recorriendo el archivo con ReadLine y ahi podes contar las lineas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso podrías hacer uso de la clase [**StreamReader**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.8) y obtener cada linea de tu archivo.

En el ejemplo veo que buscas una palabra no importando si esta palabra se encuentra con mayúsculas o minúsculas:

```
Palabra: TRACKING ID Numero de Linea: 12 Contenido: Tracking ID: 123ABCDEF
```

en este caso una opción es "normalizar" o convertir a minúsculas ambos textos, tanto el de la linea del archivo como el que intentas buscar, esto para lograr encontrar la coincidencia:

```
linea.ToLower().Contains(palabraBuscar.ToLower()
```

de esta forma podrías obtener el resultado deseado:

```
           var filepath = @"C:/MyText.txt";

           string palabraBuscar = "TRACKING";
           String linea;                
           int counter=1; 
            StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filepath);
            while ((linea = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (linea.ToLower().Contains(palabraBuscar.ToLower())){
                    //Al encontrar la palabra, imprime resultado y termina el bucle.
                    Console.WriteLine("Palabra: \"" + palabraBuscar + "\" Numero de Linea: " + counter + " Contenido: \"" + linea + "\"");
                    break;
                }
                counter++;
            }
```

ejemplo de salida:

```
Palabra: "TRACKING" Numero de Linea: 12 Contenido: "Tracking ID: 123ABCDEF"
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con el siguiente código:

```
int cont_line = 0;
string search_word = "Tracking ID: 123ABCDEF";
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\MyText.txt");

Console.WriteLine("La palabra:" + "{0}" + " se encontró en las siguientes líneas. \n", search_word);

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    cont_line++;

    if (line.Contains(search_word))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Linea: {0} - Contenido de la linea: {1}", cont_line, line);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("\n");
Console.WriteLine("El archivo tiene: {0} líneas", cont_line);


System.Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, es importante comentar que es lo que realiza el código y de que forma ayudaría a solucionar el problema planteado en la pregunta, revisa [answer], saludos.